# simple_form_for undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I receive the following error when building a basic form to create new data.  When I hit submit I get

> simple_form_for undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

```
**_form.html.erb**
<%= simple_form_for(@calls) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :caller_name %>
  <%= f.input :caller_phone, hint: "xxx-xxx-xxxx" %>
  <%= f.input :caller_address %>
  <%= f.input :primary_diagnosis %>
  <%= f.error :base %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>

**calls_controller.rb**
def create
     @call = Call.new(params[:call])

     respond_to do |format|
       if @call.save
         format.html { redirect_to @call, notice: 'Call was successfully created.' }
         format.json { render json: @call, status: :created, location: @call }
       else
         format.html { render action: "new" }
         format.json { render json: @call.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
     end
   end

**new.html.erb**
<h1>New Call</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', calls_path %>
```

I'm at a bit of a lost here as I've followed rails naming conventions, even tried this with a scaffold with the same result.  Already restarted the webrick as well.  Help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking for a `simple_form_for(@calls)`

Yet your controller is creating `@call`

You should change

```
<%= simple_form_for(@calls) do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= simple_form_for(@call) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you set `@call` in the controller, I  believe you need to pass it to the partial. See part 3.4.4 on this page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

The tag should look like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :calls=> @calls} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have a "new" method defined in your controller. Just create a new empty instance and give it back to the view.

```
def new
     @call = Call.new
end
```

The "create" method is a response for the POST action, when you send back a form with contents. Then you create a new instance from the params received and save it to the database.